# Linux/Cygwin recursively copy file change extension

Tags: linux, find, rsync, xargs, cp

I'm looking for a way to recursively find files with extension X (*.js) and make a copy of the file in the same directory with extension Y (*.ts).

e.g. /foo/bar/foobar.js --> /foo/bar/foobar.js  and /foo/bar/foobar.ts

/foo/bar.js --> /foo/bar.js and /foo/bar.ts etc etc

My due diligence:
I was thinking of using find & xargs & cp and brace expansion (`cp foobar.{js,ts}`) but xargs uses the braces to denote the list of files passed from xargs. This makes me sad as I just recently discovered the awesome-sauce that is brace expansion/substitution.

I feel like there has to be a one-line solution but I'm struggling to come up with one.

I've found ideas for performing the task: copying the desired to a new directory and then merging this directory with the new one; recursively run a renaming script in each directory; copy using rsync; use find, xargs and cpio.

As it stands it appears that running a renaming script script like [this](http://www.debianadmin.com/rename-multiple-files-to-another-extension-in-linux.html) is what I'll end up doing.

Comment: Maybe better to ask http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `xargs` does not interpret `{}` specially. How do you want to get just `foobar` from `foobar.js` in xargs, though?

Comment: I have used {} for the argument list in xargs. I guess I assumed that was the way to do it. Ooops. Regardless, if there is a way to perform some sed/awk/bash magic on the argument list passed to xargs to get the desired name change I'd be happy. I'm assuming that @choroba doesn't know how either?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
find . -name "*.js" -exec bash -c 'name="{}"; cp "$name" "${name%.js}.ts"' \;
```

Using [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/find.html), you can execute a command directly on a file that you've found, by using the `-exec` option; you don't need to pipe it through xargs. It takes the command name followed by arguments to the command, followed by a single argument `;`, which you have to escape to avoid the shell interpreting it. `find` will replace any occurrence of `{}` in the command name or arguments with the file found.

In order call a command with the appropriate ending substituted, there are multiple approaches you can take, but a simple one is to use Bash's [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). You need to define a shell parameter that contains the name (in this case, I creatively chose `name={}`), and then you can use parameter expansion on it. `${variable%suffix}` strips off `suffix` from the value of `$variable`; I then add on `.ts` to the end, and have the name I'm looking for.

Comment: Thanks much. I had just been reading up on -exec after seeing it used in some posts.

Comment: Could someone explain the use of the trailing \;  I understand the rest of the command but am curious as to the effect of that trailing slash.

Comment: @NKlosterman No problem! I've updated my answer with quoting to make it a bit safer if you have files which have spaces in their names, and provided some links. The trailing `\;` is to tell `find` when the arguments to `-exec` have stopped. It is looking for one argument which consists of a `;`, but by default, the shell will interpret that as a delimiter for the end of the `find` command, so you need to quote it. You could also write `';'`, but that's more characters than `\;`.

Comment: ....I think you mean '-exec allows you to execute a command directly on a file found using find....'

Comment: @NKlosterman Ah, there is a bit of an ambiguity in how I phrased it. I meant "execute a command [on a file found] using `-exec`, not "execute a command [on a file found using `-exec`]". I'll rephrase to make it more clear.