# Linux shell script - find all files and run a command on each one of them

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to port a windows batch file to a linux shell script (bash).

Here is the part that is giving me some headache:

```
for /r %%G in (*Metadata*.xml) DO (
java -jar %SAXON%\saxon9he.jar -o:%%~nG.csv "%%G" %WORKDIR%\transformBQT.xsl)
```

What this does is find all .xml file containing the text *Metadata* and then running the an XSLT transformation on each of these files. This takes 3 arguments

- -o is the output file (this will be a .csv with the same name as the .xml)
- next is the target file
- final argument is the .xsl file

I am thinking of using the following:

```
find /results/ -type f -name "*Metadata*.xml" -exec 
java -jar $SAXON/saxon9he.jar -o:??? {} $WORKDIR/transformXMI.xsl
```

but this doesn't quite work as I don't know how to make the output file have the same name as the .xml (with .csv extension)

Any tips?

Comment: The same name as the XSL? Don't you mean the same name as the XML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could process the results from `find` line by line and transform `<file>.xml` into `<file>.csv`:

```
find /results/ -type f -name "*Metadata*.xml" | while read file; do java -jar $SAXON/saxon9h3.jar -o:${file%.xml}.csv $file $WORKDIR/transform.XMI.xsl; done
```

This simple approach fails in case the file names have spaces in their paths/names.

Comment: Almost there. The output files are called <name>.xml.out (I used csv instead of out, but it's still the same issue.). I should be able to work this out from here though. Thanks!

Comment: I updated the answer based on @voithos input. Now xml is replaced with csv.

Comment: I think I like this approach better than executing a bash shell for every file.

Comment: Ok, I've tried numerous variations, but I can't get this to work. In the following command: `java -jar $SAXON/saxon9he.jar -o:${file%.xml}.csv $file $WORKDIR/transformXMI.xsl; done` the output file `${file%.xml}.csv` gets generated in the same folder as the `$file`. How can I make sure that the output file is created in the current folder where I execute my script? If I use a fixed output file (say. `out.csv`) it indeed gets created in the current folder!

Comment: Ok, sorted! All I had to do is use `basename`

Answer (score 1):

Per the docs, the string `{}` is replaced by the current file name bring processed. With that, along with using Bash's [parameter expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12923680/716118), you should be able to rename the output files to CSV.

```
find /results/ -type f -name "*Metadata*.xml" -exec 
bash -c 'fname="{}"; java -jar $SAXON/saxon9he.jar -o:"${fname%.xml}.csv" "$fname" $WORKDIR/transformXMI.xsl' \;
```

The important bit here is the shell parameters that you create when you execute Bash. `fname="{}"` creates a new shell parameter with the contents of the current XML file. After you have that, you can use parameter expansions: `${fname%.xml}` strips of the `.xml` extension, which is then replaced with `.csv`.